# osxの通知センターのpush通知のデザインを変更したい

Tags: macos, notification

デフォルトの通知センターのスタイリッシュなデザインに飽きたのでポップな感じに変更したいです

まず初めにswiftでの制御を試みましたが,swiftは自分のアプリケーションの通知しかコントロールできないように見えました

次にkextでの変更を考えましたが通知センターがアプリケーションであるようだったので干渉は難しいと思いました

現時点では,デフォルトの通知センターのアプリケーション位置に自作の通知センターを据え換えて動作させるのがいいのではないかと思っています

通知センターのプログラミングについて何か知っている方はいませんか？

Comment: こちらは日本語版スタックオーバーフローです。日本人で、英語が得意でないのであれば、無理に英語を使う必要はありません。(と言うか、日本語での質疑を意図したサイトなので、英語での質問は原則受け付けられません。)「編集」機能を使用して日本語で質問していただくか、英語版のStackOverflowを意図していたのであれば、こちらは削除して[本家英語版のサイト](https://stackoverflow.com)に再度書き込んでください。

Comment: 日本語に書き換えました。ありがとう。